# Timestamp day and month swapped after inserting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that opens a template file and then places the date of today in a cell. But when this day is 12 or below it swapped the day and the month. My guess is that VBA uses American date. How do i swap this ot Europe date?

In the code i format the date as: dd/MM/yyyy

This is my full code:

```
    With Workbooks("Projectsjabloon.xlsm").Sheets("Planning")
    .Range("D1").Value = Format(Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
    .Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
    False, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, 
    AllowFiltering:=True
    .SaveAs (ProjectFile), FileFormat:=52
    End With
```

Comment: What are your international date settings set to for your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend replacing this line in your code:

```
.Range("D1").Value = Format(Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

with:

```
.Range("D1").FormulaLocal = Date
```

- If you only want the date (and not the time component), better to call `Date` instead of `Now`.
- My understanding is that `Range.FormulaLocal` will take care of any locale-related issues for you (per your application settings).
- Works for me (in that I get `dd/mm/yyyy` output).

Comment: This works great for me. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to format the cell to your desired date format:

```
.Range("D1").NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

you can also use following code to change it to use your local format codes like you would do it in Excel itself

```
.Range("D1").NumberFormatLocal = "TT/MM/JJJJ"
```

(in this case it's the German format, T = Tag/Day, M = Monat/Month, J = Jahr/Year)

Answer (score 0):

Correct, VBA "speaks" American so the date will be interpreted using American format.

Just to add one more solution to the thread, you can use `.Range("D1").Value = Format(Now() - 1, "yyyy-mm-dd")` instead of `.Range("D1").Value = Format(Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy")`. Note that I needed to use `Now() - 1` to replicate yesterday's date!

`yyyy-mm-dd` is the most universal and recognised date format (as it follows ISO standards), so VBA will be able to interpret and convert the date correctly.

Previous result:
[image]

New result:
[image]